# Jtds SetFloat inputs Uneven Values in Database(Miscrosoft Sql Server)

Tags: java

I am trying to input values in sql server database using setfloat

jtdsproc.setFloat(12, nb.getOpenAmount());

My amount is 1.20
But in database it is entering 1.199999523
I just want to enter till 2 digits but this set float making Problem
How to enter float value so that it goes till two decimal .

I am Using Jtds Library to connect to sql server

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot exactly represent the number 1.2 using floating point numbers. This is because the denominator of 1.2=6/5 is not a power of two. Usually you'd design your database scheme to store a fixed number of decimals if such things matter. In that case, even if Java were transferring a value not exactly equal to 1.2, the database would still store a value of exactly 1.2.

As an alternative, you yould try to transfer the value as a string. You can use a [`DecimalFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/index.html?java/text/DecimalFormat.html) to generate a representation with a fixed number of digits, then transfer that string to the database and let it handle conversion to internal representation on the database server. Whether this works any better depends on whether the database server has more precision thand a single-precision float. If not, the stored number will likely be the same as before.

Comment: Yes i got it now . I did by adding string . But when i have 4 as a number then it is not adding .00 at the end .

Comment: Can Is any way to add 4.00 at the end. condition i do not need to check by some logic using DecimalFormat only

Comment: @SureshBora: 4 and 4.00 are the same number, so unless you *store* your data as strings, then which of these you see depends not on the data base and its content, but on the application presenting the data to you.